# Unity Minimize Battery Usage

Tags: c#, cross-platform, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple non-game app that is a couple different UI pages to simplify. Is it possible to make this in unity and not be a heavy battery destroyer?

I know that unity is a game engine at its core and is not ideal for non-game apps, but its so freakin user friendly and customizable I would rather use Unity than anything else if i can. I guess I'm wondering if it's viable to make this kind of app in Unity, or/and possible to reduce battery usage so that it becomes more viable.

If its not a viable in any form to make a small non-game app using Unity then I will sadly understand, just looking for expert input on the topic and its viability.

Thanks

p.s. If Unity is not viable, is there any other c# or similar cross platform you'd recommend for the job?

Comment: Use Xamarin instead of Unity for such stuff. Unity is definitly not the right thing if you do not want to use any of its functionality besides the rendering of a few sprites.

Answer (score -1):

The **Quality Settings** inspector (menu: **Edit > Project Settings > Quality**) is used to select the quality level in the editor for the chosen device. It is split into two main areas - at the top, there is the following matrix:

[image]

You can click on the name of a quality level to select it for editing, which is done in the panel below the settings matrix:

[image]

Source:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html

Retrieved at 5 Dec 2017